# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to elasticsearch port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, remote-server

I'm trying to connect to Elasticsearch from a laravel project. When I'm starting all services by docker-compose on a remote ubuntu (not my local machine), I get this error

```
In CurlFactory.php line 185:
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to elasticsearch port 9200: Connection refused
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
      image: my_image_name
      ports:
      - 9200:9200
      networks:
      - overlay
  website:
      image: my_image_name
      ports:
      - 80:80
      links:
      - elasticsearch
      networks:
      - overlay
      environment:
      - ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
networks:
  overlay:
```

I can access Elasticsearch by went to `ip_address:9200`. Here is what I got

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "name": "Greer Grant",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "version": {
    "number": "1.7.5",
    "build_hash": "00f95f4ffca6de89d68b7ccaf80d148f1f70e4d4",
    "build_timestamp": "2016-02-02T09:55:30Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Some answers said that I've to change `network.host` to `0.0.0.0` in `elasticsearch.yml` but I don't have access to that file because I'm using a custom pre-built image for Elasticsearch. So is there anyway that I can overwrite `network.host` through docker-`compose.yml` file ?

Comment: The `links: [elasticsearch]` block activates an obsolete Docker networking mode which I've seen suspected in some other SO questions.  Does deleting it make any difference?  (You don't need it at all with Docker networks.)

Comment: I commented out that line but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: why are you using Elasticsearch 1.7? it's super old and no longer supported

Comment: it is an old project and I don't have the right to update them (it takes effort and I don't know much about elasticsearch actually)